# Identify blocks/groups of words in a document based on a key word and positional data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, coordinates, gravity

Considering the we have following input data table.

```
import pandas as pd
#Pandas settings to see all the data when printing
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  # or 1000
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)  # or 1000
pd.set_option('display.width', 500)

#Load the data
data_array = [[576, 60, 279, 28, 2, 'LzR', 0, 0], [578, 17, 318, 23, 3, 'U', 0, 0], [371, 21, 279, 24, 2, 'K', 0, 0], [373, 134, 317, 25, 3, 'mq77MJc', 0, 0], [537, 32, 317, 25, 3, '53', 0, 0], [373, 201, 355, 25, 4, '7Q7NZzkAzN', 0, 0], [538, 118, 393, 24, 5, 'oNNbgA', 0, 0], [680, 39, 392, 26, 5, 'J9', 0, 0], [1509, 155, 260, 154, 2, 'd', 0, 0], [1731, 98, 268, 123, 2, 'z8', 0, 0], [1876, 385, 271, 120, 2, 'rUqNDY', 0, 0], [1640, 197, 590, 21, 7, 't5gNVHDXQVJ', 0, 0], [1989, 270, 589, 22, 7, 't3I81fBOE9caUfb', 0, 0], [352, 80, 645, 25, 8, 'i5f3', 0, 1], [454, 245, 645, 25, 8, 'KrqcRA7Se7X7', 1, 1], [719, 60, 645, 27, 8, 'bpN', 0, 1], [1640, 161, 642, 22, 8, 'skAzt6Np4', 0, 0], [1822, 51, 643, 21, 8, 'K59', 0, 0], [2082, 177, 642, 22, 8, 'cwyN7wsMhE', 0, 0], [353, 220, 683, 25, 9, 'O8coFUwMUbE', 0, 1], [597, 17, 683, 25, 9, 'L', 0, 1], [1640, 234, 695, 22, 9, 'oVWEKowWnbT2y', 0, 0], [2080, 179, 695, 22, 9, 'FvjigCiC7h', 0, 0], [351, 79, 721, 24, 10, 'OQN3', 0, 1], [476, 202, 720, 25, 10, 'S2gcfJIDze', 0, 1], [2062, 69, 775, 22, 11, 'n9lN', 0, 0], [2155, 8, 775, 21, 11, 'G', 0, 0], [2188, 35, 775, 21, 11, '9X', 0, 0], [2246, 8, 775, 21, 11, 'v', 0, 0], [353, 81, 1003, 21, 13, 'c7ox8', 0, 0], [461, 325, 1003, 22, 13, 'o9GmMYAW4RrpPBY64p', 0, 0], [351, 101, 1037, 22, 14, '9NF7ii', 0, 0], [477, 146, 1037, 21, 14, 'MwTlIkU9', 0, 0], [350, 70, 1071, 22, 15, 'J5XF', 0, 0], [443, 87, 1071, 22, 15, '3m4tM', 0, 0], [553, 32, 1071, 22, 15, 'Ck', 0, 0], [609, 10, 1071, 22, 15, '5', 0, 0], [643, 53, 1071, 22, 15, 'X7Y', 0, 0], [1568, 135, 1092, 20, 16, 'P4', 0, 0], [352, 142, 1105, 22, 16, 'Pjs1GYSG', 0, 0], [516, 45, 1105, 22, 16, 'o9V', 0, 0], [588, 106, 1105, 22, 16, 'WRI8oY', 0, 0], [1563, 132, 1117, 20, 16, '3cZY', 0, 0], [350, 69, 1140, 21, 17, 'GW3y', 0, 0], [441, 35, 1139, 22, 17, 'EO', 0, 0], [497, 51, 1139, 28, 17, 'toN', 0, 0], [570, 49, 1140, 21, 17, 'k11', 0, 0], [643, 51, 1139, 22, 17, 'pod', 0, 0], [715, 89, 1140, 21, 17, '6SQfv', 0, 0], [825, 83, 1139, 22, 17, 'CzC2M', 0, 0], [934, 102, 1140, 21, 17, 'aowjQC', 0, 0], [1062, 51, 1140, 21, 17, 'BtC', 0, 0], [1558, 136, 1142, 20, 17, 'XhJ', 0, 0], [1722, 336, 1115, 25, 16, 'OgtXP2nxOwP7Gb3I', 0, 0], [352, 125, 1174, 21, 18, 'zYmvutc', 0, 0], [498, 45, 1174, 21, 18, 'JvN', 0, 0], [570, 124, 1174, 21, 18, 'TyZdJG4', 0, 0], [352, 64, 1207, 22, 19, 'Lvam', 0, 0], [443, 45, 1208, 21, 19, 'Onk', 0, 0], [516, 123, 1208, 21, 19, 'bPgi7tF', 0, 0], [1946, 12, 1231, 11, 20, 'I', 0, 0], [351, 106, 1241, 23, 20, 'xbAa7n', 0, 0], [479, 306, 1242, 22, 20, 'NEn7uifO17vkyzVVp', 0, 0], [1300, 142, 1242, 27, 20, 'dZukserV', 0, 0], [352, 178, 1275, 34, 21, 'qrxWKyJjjn', 0, 0], [557, 60, 1275, 28, 21, '2Ri5', 0, 0], [1354, 88, 1276, 27, 21, 'ZCp3F', 0, 0], [1558, 197, 1231, 63, 20, 'YgoGs', 0, 0], [1787, 96, 1247, 63, 20, 'Um', 0, 0], [1913, 268, 1231, 63, 20, 'YL7fkaV', 0, 0], [351, 70, 1309, 23, 22, 'kcGD', 0, 0], [443, 142, 1309, 23, 22, 'lGAx6Ljx', 0, 0], [605, 35, 1310, 21, 22, 'Hm', 0, 0], [661, 142, 1310, 27, 22, 'S8gZ5tPE', 0, 0], [1302, 135, 1310, 27, 22, 'gjgVPImz', 0, 0], [1743, 12, 1329, 11, 23, 'Z', 0, 0], [2055, 16, 1324, 17, 23, 'i', 0, 0], [353, 11, 1344, 21, 24, 'L', 0, 0], [386, 53, 1344, 21, 24, 'Q5J', 0, 0], [1300, 142, 1344, 27, 24, '9L9ScEj2', 0, 0], [1558, 400, 1345, 63, 24, 'S8YyUDnXd', 0, 0], [1993, 91, 1345, 62, 24, '4P', 0, 0], [1555, 102, 1605, 35, 25, 'kbGP', 0, 2], [1674, 371, 1605, 44, 25, 'DO1tvoEyiX9AVz6Q', 0, 2], [2062, 147, 1605, 44, 25, 'DtQAa3', 2, 2], [1554, 53, 1669, 35, 26, 'pg', 0, 2], [1624, 104, 1660, 34, 26, 'ZPsJ', 0, 2], [1746, 221, 1659, 38, 26, '7CBPYAUA', 0, 2], [1987, 50, 1657, 46, 26, 'AL', 0, 2], [1555, 407, 1714, 44, 27, 'LA3ShdHUE3DAoOkfiB', 0, 2], [188, 1826, 2340, 3, 29, '4', 0, 0], [2024, 217, 2309, 34, 28, 'DLpZXhKepjdcyW', 0, 0], [2239, 119, 2310, 33, 28, '28otEfj9', 0, 0], [230, 77, 2349, 23, 29, 'Th1YC4R', 0, 0], [476, 89, 2349, 18, 29, 'uFRt5qEx', 0, 0], [1140, 463, 2388, 35, 30, 'Mxcsoj1MOubuEB33', 0, 0], [1708, 40, 2372, 17, 30, 'OfA', 0, 9], [1758, 81, 2372, 22, 30, 'ZQoO7mwr', 0, 9], [1848, 3, 2372, 17, 30, 'M', 0, 9], [1860, 134, 2372, 22, 30, 'IvtUnQ4Zxc29A', 0, 9], [2002, 20, 2376, 13, 30, '3V', 0, 9], [2029, 32, 2372, 17, 30, '6t8', 0, 9], [2070, 133, 2372, 17, 30, 'PdCWscuWGHR', 0, 9], [1709, 171, 2398, 22, 30, 'RsW4Oj1Lhf1ljQV4G', 0, 9], [1890, 148, 2398, 22, 30, 'VSUJUa3tuYIhiXxP', 9, 9], [2048, 34, 2398, 17, 30, 'aAm', 0, 9], [2089, 21, 2403, 12, 30, 'uY', 0, 9], [2118, 53, 2398, 17, 30, '6DDFv', 0, 9], [2179, 28, 2398, 17, 30, 'DKJ', 0, 9], [2214, 66, 2398, 17, 30, 'NBmY9BD', 0, 9], [2289, 57, 2398, 18, 30, 'sYsrT', 0, 9], [1708, 25, 2425, 17, 31, 'jGk', 0, 9], [1736, 34, 2429, 13, 31, 'oX', 0, 9], [1778, 93, 2425, 17, 31, 'OvpfEyhHso', 0, 9], [120, 131, 2510, 23, 32, 'rZCsYsA6im2b', 0, 0], [260, 25, 2515, 18, 32, 'G6', 0, 0], [295, 107, 2510, 18, 32, 'd6eYwhzZuS', 0, 0], [132, 88, 2582, 22, 34, 'Xc84', 3, 3], [231, 223, 2582, 22, 34, 'MnMcBUHVmhl2', 0, 3], [463, 47, 2582, 22, 34, 'Vto', 0, 3], [132, 194, 2616, 22, 35, 'B4f1f4KpCHC', 0, 3], [338, 14, 2616, 22, 35, 'W', 0, 3], [131, 64, 2650, 22, 36, 'UW6t', 0, 3], [216, 181, 2650, 22, 36, 'hLULWi7xdj', 0, 3], [1044, 175, 2510, 18, 32, 'F9f7jvsfmjnXbK', 0, 0], [1226, 25, 2515, 18, 32, 'Vk', 0, 0], [1261, 177, 2510, 23, 32, 'TBlYLSoItzHKpG', 0, 0], [1054, 132, 2544, 22, 33, 'u4vvPgHd', 0, 0], [1053, 36, 2590, 21, 34, 'lN', 0, 4], [1101, 107, 2589, 23, 34, 'ieee4D', 0, 4], [1218, 47, 2589, 23, 34, 'kD6', 0, 4], [1054, 122, 2623, 23, 35, 'Ngf2xWa', 0, 4], [1189, 132, 2624, 22, 35, 'N27RyHsP', 0, 4], [1054, 204, 2657, 23, 36, 'e97JFxWTXfS', 0, 4], [1262, 43, 2658, 22, 36, 'p', 4, 4], [1054, 65, 2692, 22, 37, 'mle1', 0, 4], [1139, 186, 2691, 23, 37, 'o6tA5wFrK', 0, 4], [1337, 39, 2691, 23, 37, 'W3', 0, 4], [1709, 175, 2510, 18, 32, 'DQm27gIhcjmkdB', 0, 0], [1892, 25, 2515, 18, 32, '4Z', 0, 0], [1927, 176, 2510, 23, 32, 'rAP1PxzMyqkxdY', 0, 0], [1720, 132, 2544, 22, 33, 'JpsQeikW', 0, 0], [1719, 35, 2590, 21, 34, 'hD', 0, 5], [1766, 107, 2589, 23, 34, '3vzIwR', 0, 5], [1884, 47, 2589, 23, 34, 'kHw', 0, 5], [1720, 122, 2623, 23, 35, 'MYOKedL', 0, 5], [1854, 132, 2624, 22, 35, 'K8JXFVII', 5, 5], [1720, 204, 2657, 23, 36, 'bBkPRmgyfVp', 0, 5], [1928, 43, 2658, 22, 36, 'j', 0, 5], [1719, 65, 2692, 22, 37, 'RfU4', 0, 5], [1805, 185, 2691, 23, 37, 'wtK1L23Q4', 0, 5], [2003, 38, 2692, 22, 37, 'yY', 0, 5], [130, 255, 2804, 23, 38, 'jgoGjNh2DoLnb2b4PGonGvU', 0, 0], [1044, 117, 2804, 18, 38, 'qGXS7f7gRHy', 0, 0], [1168, 38, 2804, 18, 38, 'UQI', 0, 0], [1215, 102, 2804, 18, 38, 'P764bscKkx', 0, 0], [1320, 38, 2804, 18, 38, 'OtH', 0, 0], [1368, 58, 2804, 18, 38, 'VhrUJ', 0, 0], [1709, 100, 2804, 23, 38, 'zjQgoufCGU', 0, 0], [131, 55, 2852, 21, 40, 'piH', 0, 0], [198, 41, 2858, 15, 40, 'wU6P', 0, 0], [281, 124, 2852, 21, 40, 'riQCT4RX', 0, 0], [454, 138, 2852, 27, 40, 'jSAJPlWhyRE', 0, 0], [612, 77, 2852, 21, 40, 'nVS97', 0, 0], [131, 227, 2886, 21, 41, 'zExU7Poi4QW', 0, 0], [375, 235, 2886, 21, 41, 'pLTfHVP1qzb7Mh2', 0, 0], [138, 100, 2957, 15, 42, 'fv8', 0, 0], [1404, 4, 2978, 4, 42, 'B', 0, 0], [130, 103, 2975, 34, 42, 'qpg', 0, 0], [253, 252, 2974, 19, 42, 'T9SOmYWl4CUrdt8o', 0, 0], [1078, 3, 2972, 40, 42, 'S5', 0, 0], [1103, 62, 2978, 28, 42, 'L6W', 0, 0], [1181, 56, 2978, 28, 42, 'ep1', 0, 0], [1253, 118, 2978, 28, 42, 'oKhrqlI', 0, 0], [1384, 45, 2985, 21, 42, 'OyP', 0, 0], [1444, 132, 2978, 28, 42, 'mvg8Bw5', 0, 0], [1593, 55, 2972, 76, 42, 'eG', 0, 0], [218, 5, 3074, 18, 44, 'z', 0, 0], [231, 72, 3058, 18, 44, 'x1Pat7', 0, 0], [605, 5, 3074, 18, 44, 'P', 0, 0], [617, 39, 3058, 18, 44, 'dNT', 0, 0], [1053, 146, 3058, 23, 44, 'q7CLeOJhnI1oa', 0, 0], [1802, 5, 3074, 18, 44, '6', 0, 0], [1815, 72, 3058, 18, 44, 'acKa9h', 0, 0], [2119, 50, 3057, 35, 44, 'uGH', 0, 0], [461, 129, 3125, 29, 45, 'p6L5U', 0, 0], [623, 44, 3125, 29, 45, 'dC', 0, 0], [1046, 266, 3125, 29, 45, '9HBoqUyRbg', 0, 0], [1975, 129, 3125, 29, 45, 'qH1ph', 0, 0], [2136, 45, 3125, 29, 45, 'gG', 0, 0], [218, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'j', 0, 0], [605, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'o', 0, 0], [119, 24, 3213, 18, 47, 'QDN', 0, 8], [153, 94, 3213, 18, 47, 'EleVpvP4', 0, 8], [256, 105, 3213, 23, 47, 'dq9L2xQO7', 0, 8], [370, 7, 3223, 2, 47, 'n', 0, 8], [386, 69, 3212, 24, 47, 'L9EKl', 0, 8], [464, 83, 3213, 23, 47, 'AnF2rBIN', 0, 8], [555, 19, 3214, 17, 47, 'k6', 0, 8], [582, 62, 3213, 18, 47, 'y3M3kx', 8, 8], [654, 2, 3213, 18, 47, '1', 0, 8], [666, 139, 3212, 19, 47, 'SkmavPFrrrSv', 0, 8], [808, 52, 3213, 18, 47, 'bJ5S', 0, 8], [200, 100, 3316, 29, 50, 'NmNa', 0, 7], [336, 675, 3316, 29, 50, 'vB759g8XWkL7XXe5tCHZs7tAF', 7, 7], [1046, 42, 3203, 23, 47, 'v4T', 0, 0], [1095, 150, 3202, 19, 47, 'NH7vM6', 0, 0], [1251, 24, 3199, 22, 47, '47', 0, 0], [1802, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'B', 0, 0], [2119, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'b', 0, 0], [1714, 254, 3213, 23, 47, '2Za9eGyQyKp4S2rVYahzJNM', 0, 0], [1715, 55, 3261, 21, 48, 'djv', 0, 6], [1781, 41, 3267, 15, 48, '3WHD', 0, 6], [1864, 124, 3261, 21, 48, '8ucAV2oj', 0, 6], [2037, 139, 3261, 27, 48, 'baUoLawp6rY', 0, 6], [2196, 76, 3261, 21, 48, 'sRheu', 6, 6], [1715, 226, 3295, 21, 49, 'hAfhkKsI7Jx', 0, 6], [1959, 234, 3295, 21, 49, 'quecbSW4gEdjSGG', 0, 6], [1715, 176, 3329, 27, 50, 'ciaZR8NxiuEXr1', 0, 6], [1910, 140, 3329, 21, 50, 'vicUyHPNcN', 0, 6]]
data_pd =  pd.DataFrame(data_array,columns=["left", "width", "top", "height", "lineNr", "randomWord", "keyWord", "keyWordGroup"])
print(data_pd)
```

The table contains a main column `randomWord` and a few other columns with positional coordinates of each word within the document.

To help visualize the data. I wrote this code which makes an image out of the table for a better visualization and understanding of the problem

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw # pip install Pillow
import random

#Create a empty image object
new_im = Image.new('RGB', ((data_pd["left"]+data_pd["width"]).max() + data_pd["left"].min(), (data_pd["top"]+data_pd["height"]).max()  + data_pd["top"].min() ), (255,255,255))
draw_new_im = ImageDraw.Draw(new_im)

#Create a dictioanry with random colors to assign for each uniq keyWordGroup
uniqGroups = data_pd["keyWordGroup"].unique()
colors = {}
for g in uniqGroups:
    if(g == 0):
        colors[str(g)] = "black" # assign black color for non groups
    else:
        colors[str(g)] =  "#"+''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)]) #generate random color

#Write text to the image
for i, row in data_pd.iterrows():
    draw_new_im.text((int(row["left"]), int(row["top"])), str(row["randomWord"]) ,  fill=colors[str(row["keyWordGroup"])],font=ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", int(row["height"])))

#Save the image
new_im.save("TestImage.jpg")
```

As you can see we have the `keyWord` column. This column contains the IDs of some key words that we need to find the closest the block/group of text they belongs to.

The question of this post is the following: **How can we identify the group/block of text closest to the key word in the `keyWord` column ?** As you see in the image generated, for each `keyWord` ID we find all the words which are in the proximity and forming a block of text.

The output that i am looking for is in column `keyWordGroup` which is an example of which words were assign to the key words.

Is there any method we could use to find these block of text based on the keywords and the rest of the positional data given?

Comment: Some entries in the keyWordGroup column are set to 0. IIUC they don't belong to any keyword, right? Then what is the criterion for not including a word to any keyword group: is there a maximum distance or a maximum number of keywords per group or a certain share of words that should be put into one of the groups?

Comment: Just to get that straight, you want to find out word clusters and label them in a `keyWordGroup` flag?

Comment: @Stef  yes that is correct, entries with 0 in keyWordGroup do not belong to any keyword group. The criteria is finding the blocks of text in the proximity of the keyword. you can see better in the image. There is specific max or min distance as it depends on the size of the text block. There is no min or max nr of words either because again it depends on the size of the text block.

Comment: @norok2 yes exactly what i need. but it needs to be positional based not word based. Basically finding all the words in the block in which the specific keyword belongs to.

Comment: I have a solution currently which is calculating clusters of words based on their position and the distance between the lines. The output is the center of gravity the text block. Then it recalculates all the distances from the center of gravity of the text blocks and finds the words inside it. If the keyword belongs to that  specific bag of words then it marks all the words inside as to that keywords group. The problem with my current solution is that it is extremely slow and has many loops

Comment: Could you perhaps abstract this a bit more? How relevant is it that at a word is at a certain position? is the word width/height to be taken into account? What do you mean by "positional based"? What you seems to be looking for is some sort of clustering algorithm; scikit-learn provides a number, and there is plenty of resources on how to use them e.g. https://stackabuse.com/hierarchical-clustering-with-python-and-scikit-learn/ BUT without more details on what exactly is need it may be difficult to help you further. If you have a slow (working) solution, that is an excellent starting point.

Comment: @norok2, i have been checking now the hierarchical-clustering and is actually really good. Thank you for the tips :) The clustering results are really impressive, the only problem is that i must define the nr of clusters beforehand, and i dont know how many blocks of text could there be in advance. And yes the word `width` and `height` gives positional information about how long is the word is and how high it is. If you take into account only the `left` and `top` without the `width` and `height` then you only position the words in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution comprises two steps:

1. Group words to closest keyword (I wouldn't call it clustering as the centers of the groups are already given here, as opposed to clustering where you try to find clusters with no a priori known locations)
2. Remove outliers that don't seem to really belong to this keyword, although this keywords is the closest by distance.

Grouping is straightforward by assigning keyword numbers by distance using [vector quantization](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.vq.html). The only thing we have to bear in mind here is that the keyword numbers in the original dataframe don't appear in ordered sequence, but in vq groups are numbered in sequence starting with 0. That's why we have to map the new keyword group numbers to the given keyword numbers.

Removing outliers can be done in different ways, and there were no strict requirements in the question on how the keyword groups should be formed. I chose a very simple approach: take the mean and standard deviation of the distances from the keyword to all keyword group members and consider words with distances greater than Mean + x * StdDev as outliers. A choice of x = 1.5 gives [good results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOH1U.jpg).

```
import pandas as pd

#Load the data
data_array = [[576, 60, 279, 28, 2, 'LzR', 0, 0], [578, 17, 318, 23, 3, 'U', 0, 0], [371, 21, 279, 24, 2, 'K', 0, 0], [373, 134, 317, 25, 3, 'mq77MJc', 0, 0], [537, 32, 317, 25, 3, '53', 0, 0], [373, 201, 355, 25, 4, '7Q7NZzkAzN', 0, 0], [538, 118, 393, 24, 5, 'oNNbgA', 0, 0], [680, 39, 392, 26, 5, 'J9', 0, 0], [1509, 155, 260, 154, 2, 'd', 0, 0], [1731, 98, 268, 123, 2, 'z8', 0, 0], [1876, 385, 271, 120, 2, 'rUqNDY', 0, 0], [1640, 197, 590, 21, 7, 't5gNVHDXQVJ', 0, 0], [1989, 270, 589, 22, 7, 't3I81fBOE9caUfb', 0, 0], [352, 80, 645, 25, 8, 'i5f3', 0, 1], [454, 245, 645, 25, 8, 'KrqcRA7Se7X7', 1, 1], [719, 60, 645, 27, 8, 'bpN', 0, 1], [1640, 161, 642, 22, 8, 'skAzt6Np4', 0, 0], [1822, 51, 643, 21, 8, 'K59', 0, 0], [2082, 177, 642, 22, 8, 'cwyN7wsMhE', 0, 0], [353, 220, 683, 25, 9, 'O8coFUwMUbE', 0, 1], [597, 17, 683, 25, 9, 'L', 0, 1], [1640, 234, 695, 22, 9, 'oVWEKowWnbT2y', 0, 0], [2080, 179, 695, 22, 9, 'FvjigCiC7h', 0, 0], [351, 79, 721, 24, 10, 'OQN3', 0, 1], [476, 202, 720, 25, 10, 'S2gcfJIDze', 0, 1], [2062, 69, 775, 22, 11, 'n9lN', 0, 0], [2155, 8, 775, 21, 11, 'G', 0, 0], [2188, 35, 775, 21, 11, '9X', 0, 0], [2246, 8, 775, 21, 11, 'v', 0, 0], [353, 81, 1003, 21, 13, 'c7ox8', 0, 0], [461, 325, 1003, 22, 13, 'o9GmMYAW4RrpPBY64p', 0, 0], [351, 101, 1037, 22, 14, '9NF7ii', 0, 0], [477, 146, 1037, 21, 14, 'MwTlIkU9', 0, 0], [350, 70, 1071, 22, 15, 'J5XF', 0, 0], [443, 87, 1071, 22, 15, '3m4tM', 0, 0], [553, 32, 1071, 22, 15, 'Ck', 0, 0], [609, 10, 1071, 22, 15, '5', 0, 0], [643, 53, 1071, 22, 15, 'X7Y', 0, 0], [1568, 135, 1092, 20, 16, 'P4', 0, 0], [352, 142, 1105, 22, 16, 'Pjs1GYSG', 0, 0], [516, 45, 1105, 22, 16, 'o9V', 0, 0], [588, 106, 1105, 22, 16, 'WRI8oY', 0, 0], [1563, 132, 1117, 20, 16, '3cZY', 0, 0], [350, 69, 1140, 21, 17, 'GW3y', 0, 0], [441, 35, 1139, 22, 17, 'EO', 0, 0], [497, 51, 1139, 28, 17, 'toN', 0, 0], [570, 49, 1140, 21, 17, 'k11', 0, 0], [643, 51, 1139, 22, 17, 'pod', 0, 0], [715, 89, 1140, 21, 17, '6SQfv', 0, 0], [825, 83, 1139, 22, 17, 'CzC2M', 0, 0], [934, 102, 1140, 21, 17, 'aowjQC', 0, 0], [1062, 51, 1140, 21, 17, 'BtC', 0, 0], [1558, 136, 1142, 20, 17, 'XhJ', 0, 0], [1722, 336, 1115, 25, 16, 'OgtXP2nxOwP7Gb3I', 0, 0], [352, 125, 1174, 21, 18, 'zYmvutc', 0, 0], [498, 45, 1174, 21, 18, 'JvN', 0, 0], [570, 124, 1174, 21, 18, 'TyZdJG4', 0, 0], [352, 64, 1207, 22, 19, 'Lvam', 0, 0], [443, 45, 1208, 21, 19, 'Onk', 0, 0], [516, 123, 1208, 21, 19, 'bPgi7tF', 0, 0], [1946, 12, 1231, 11, 20, 'I', 0, 0], [351, 106, 1241, 23, 20, 'xbAa7n', 0, 0], [479, 306, 1242, 22, 20, 'NEn7uifO17vkyzVVp', 0, 0], [1300, 142, 1242, 27, 20, 'dZukserV', 0, 0], [352, 178, 1275, 34, 21, 'qrxWKyJjjn', 0, 0], [557, 60, 1275, 28, 21, '2Ri5', 0, 0], [1354, 88, 1276, 27, 21, 'ZCp3F', 0, 0], [1558, 197, 1231, 63, 20, 'YgoGs', 0, 0], [1787, 96, 1247, 63, 20, 'Um', 0, 0], [1913, 268, 1231, 63, 20, 'YL7fkaV', 0, 0], [351, 70, 1309, 23, 22, 'kcGD', 0, 0], [443, 142, 1309, 23, 22, 'lGAx6Ljx', 0, 0], [605, 35, 1310, 21, 22, 'Hm', 0, 0], [661, 142, 1310, 27, 22, 'S8gZ5tPE', 0, 0], [1302, 135, 1310, 27, 22, 'gjgVPImz', 0, 0], [1743, 12, 1329, 11, 23, 'Z', 0, 0], [2055, 16, 1324, 17, 23, 'i', 0, 0], [353, 11, 1344, 21, 24, 'L', 0, 0], [386, 53, 1344, 21, 24, 'Q5J', 0, 0], [1300, 142, 1344, 27, 24, '9L9ScEj2', 0, 0], [1558, 400, 1345, 63, 24, 'S8YyUDnXd', 0, 0], [1993, 91, 1345, 62, 24, '4P', 0, 0], [1555, 102, 1605, 35, 25, 'kbGP', 0, 2], [1674, 371, 1605, 44, 25, 'DO1tvoEyiX9AVz6Q', 0, 2], [2062, 147, 1605, 44, 25, 'DtQAa3', 2, 2], [1554, 53, 1669, 35, 26, 'pg', 0, 2], [1624, 104, 1660, 34, 26, 'ZPsJ', 0, 2], [1746, 221, 1659, 38, 26, '7CBPYAUA', 0, 2], [1987, 50, 1657, 46, 26, 'AL', 0, 2], [1555, 407, 1714, 44, 27, 'LA3ShdHUE3DAoOkfiB', 0, 2], [188, 1826, 2340, 3, 29, '4', 0, 0], [2024, 217, 2309, 34, 28, 'DLpZXhKepjdcyW', 0, 0], [2239, 119, 2310, 33, 28, '28otEfj9', 0, 0], [230, 77, 2349, 23, 29, 'Th1YC4R', 0, 0], [476, 89, 2349, 18, 29, 'uFRt5qEx', 0, 0], [1140, 463, 2388, 35, 30, 'Mxcsoj1MOubuEB33', 0, 0], [1708, 40, 2372, 17, 30, 'OfA', 0, 9], [1758, 81, 2372, 22, 30, 'ZQoO7mwr', 0, 9], [1848, 3, 2372, 17, 30, 'M', 0, 9], [1860, 134, 2372, 22, 30, 'IvtUnQ4Zxc29A', 0, 9], [2002, 20, 2376, 13, 30, '3V', 0, 9], [2029, 32, 2372, 17, 30, '6t8', 0, 9], [2070, 133, 2372, 17, 30, 'PdCWscuWGHR', 0, 9], [1709, 171, 2398, 22, 30, 'RsW4Oj1Lhf1ljQV4G', 0, 9], [1890, 148, 2398, 22, 30, 'VSUJUa3tuYIhiXxP', 9, 9], [2048, 34, 2398, 17, 30, 'aAm', 0, 9], [2089, 21, 2403, 12, 30, 'uY', 0, 9], [2118, 53, 2398, 17, 30, '6DDFv', 0, 9], [2179, 28, 2398, 17, 30, 'DKJ', 0, 9], [2214, 66, 2398, 17, 30, 'NBmY9BD', 0, 9], [2289, 57, 2398, 18, 30, 'sYsrT', 0, 9], [1708, 25, 2425, 17, 31, 'jGk', 0, 9], [1736, 34, 2429, 13, 31, 'oX', 0, 9], [1778, 93, 2425, 17, 31, 'OvpfEyhHso', 0, 9], [120, 131, 2510, 23, 32, 'rZCsYsA6im2b', 0, 0], [260, 25, 2515, 18, 32, 'G6', 0, 0], [295, 107, 2510, 18, 32, 'd6eYwhzZuS', 0, 0], [132, 88, 2582, 22, 34, 'Xc84', 3, 3], [231, 223, 2582, 22, 34, 'MnMcBUHVmhl2', 0, 3], [463, 47, 2582, 22, 34, 'Vto', 0, 3], [132, 194, 2616, 22, 35, 'B4f1f4KpCHC', 0, 3], [338, 14, 2616, 22, 35, 'W', 0, 3], [131, 64, 2650, 22, 36, 'UW6t', 0, 3], [216, 181, 2650, 22, 36, 'hLULWi7xdj', 0, 3], [1044, 175, 2510, 18, 32, 'F9f7jvsfmjnXbK', 0, 0], [1226, 25, 2515, 18, 32, 'Vk', 0, 0], [1261, 177, 2510, 23, 32, 'TBlYLSoItzHKpG', 0, 0], [1054, 132, 2544, 22, 33, 'u4vvPgHd', 0, 0], [1053, 36, 2590, 21, 34, 'lN', 0, 4], [1101, 107, 2589, 23, 34, 'ieee4D', 0, 4], [1218, 47, 2589, 23, 34, 'kD6', 0, 4], [1054, 122, 2623, 23, 35, 'Ngf2xWa', 0, 4], [1189, 132, 2624, 22, 35, 'N27RyHsP', 0, 4], [1054, 204, 2657, 23, 36, 'e97JFxWTXfS', 0, 4], [1262, 43, 2658, 22, 36, 'p', 4, 4], [1054, 65, 2692, 22, 37, 'mle1', 0, 4], [1139, 186, 2691, 23, 37, 'o6tA5wFrK', 0, 4], [1337, 39, 2691, 23, 37, 'W3', 0, 4], [1709, 175, 2510, 18, 32, 'DQm27gIhcjmkdB', 0, 0], [1892, 25, 2515, 18, 32, '4Z', 0, 0], [1927, 176, 2510, 23, 32, 'rAP1PxzMyqkxdY', 0, 0], [1720, 132, 2544, 22, 33, 'JpsQeikW', 0, 0], [1719, 35, 2590, 21, 34, 'hD', 0, 5], [1766, 107, 2589, 23, 34, '3vzIwR', 0, 5], [1884, 47, 2589, 23, 34, 'kHw', 0, 5], [1720, 122, 2623, 23, 35, 'MYOKedL', 0, 5], [1854, 132, 2624, 22, 35, 'K8JXFVII', 5, 5], [1720, 204, 2657, 23, 36, 'bBkPRmgyfVp', 0, 5], [1928, 43, 2658, 22, 36, 'j', 0, 5], [1719, 65, 2692, 22, 37, 'RfU4', 0, 5], [1805, 185, 2691, 23, 37, 'wtK1L23Q4', 0, 5], [2003, 38, 2692, 22, 37, 'yY', 0, 5], [130, 255, 2804, 23, 38, 'jgoGjNh2DoLnb2b4PGonGvU', 0, 0], [1044, 117, 2804, 18, 38, 'qGXS7f7gRHy', 0, 0], [1168, 38, 2804, 18, 38, 'UQI', 0, 0], [1215, 102, 2804, 18, 38, 'P764bscKkx', 0, 0], [1320, 38, 2804, 18, 38, 'OtH', 0, 0], [1368, 58, 2804, 18, 38, 'VhrUJ', 0, 0], [1709, 100, 2804, 23, 38, 'zjQgoufCGU', 0, 0], [131, 55, 2852, 21, 40, 'piH', 0, 0], [198, 41, 2858, 15, 40, 'wU6P', 0, 0], [281, 124, 2852, 21, 40, 'riQCT4RX', 0, 0], [454, 138, 2852, 27, 40, 'jSAJPlWhyRE', 0, 0], [612, 77, 2852, 21, 40, 'nVS97', 0, 0], [131, 227, 2886, 21, 41, 'zExU7Poi4QW', 0, 0], [375, 235, 2886, 21, 41, 'pLTfHVP1qzb7Mh2', 0, 0], [138, 100, 2957, 15, 42, 'fv8', 0, 0], [1404, 4, 2978, 4, 42, 'B', 0, 0], [130, 103, 2975, 34, 42, 'qpg', 0, 0], [253, 252, 2974, 19, 42, 'T9SOmYWl4CUrdt8o', 0, 0], [1078, 3, 2972, 40, 42, 'S5', 0, 0], [1103, 62, 2978, 28, 42, 'L6W', 0, 0], [1181, 56, 2978, 28, 42, 'ep1', 0, 0], [1253, 118, 2978, 28, 42, 'oKhrqlI', 0, 0], [1384, 45, 2985, 21, 42, 'OyP', 0, 0], [1444, 132, 2978, 28, 42, 'mvg8Bw5', 0, 0], [1593, 55, 2972, 76, 42, 'eG', 0, 0], [218, 5, 3074, 18, 44, 'z', 0, 0], [231, 72, 3058, 18, 44, 'x1Pat7', 0, 0], [605, 5, 3074, 18, 44, 'P', 0, 0], [617, 39, 3058, 18, 44, 'dNT', 0, 0], [1053, 146, 3058, 23, 44, 'q7CLeOJhnI1oa', 0, 0], [1802, 5, 3074, 18, 44, '6', 0, 0], [1815, 72, 3058, 18, 44, 'acKa9h', 0, 0], [2119, 50, 3057, 35, 44, 'uGH', 0, 0], [461, 129, 3125, 29, 45, 'p6L5U', 0, 0], [623, 44, 3125, 29, 45, 'dC', 0, 0], [1046, 266, 3125, 29, 45, '9HBoqUyRbg', 0, 0], [1975, 129, 3125, 29, 45, 'qH1ph', 0, 0], [2136, 45, 3125, 29, 45, 'gG', 0, 0], [218, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'j', 0, 0], [605, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'o', 0, 0], [119, 24, 3213, 18, 47, 'QDN', 0, 8], [153, 94, 3213, 18, 47, 'EleVpvP4', 0, 8], [256, 105, 3213, 23, 47, 'dq9L2xQO7', 0, 8], [370, 7, 3223, 2, 47, 'n', 0, 8], [386, 69, 3212, 24, 47, 'L9EKl', 0, 8], [464, 83, 3213, 23, 47, 'AnF2rBIN', 0, 8], [555, 19, 3214, 17, 47, 'k6', 0, 8], [582, 62, 3213, 18, 47, 'y3M3kx', 8, 8], [654, 2, 3213, 18, 47, '1', 0, 8], [666, 139, 3212, 19, 47, 'SkmavPFrrrSv', 0, 8], [808, 52, 3213, 18, 47, 'bJ5S', 0, 8], [200, 100, 3316, 29, 50, 'NmNa', 0, 7], [336, 675, 3316, 29, 50, 'vB759g8XWkL7XXe5tCHZs7tAF', 7, 7], [1046, 42, 3203, 23, 47, 'v4T', 0, 0], [1095, 150, 3202, 19, 47, 'NH7vM6', 0, 0], [1251, 24, 3199, 22, 47, '47', 0, 0], [1802, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'B', 0, 0], [2119, 5, 3183, 20, 46, 'b', 0, 0], [1714, 254, 3213, 23, 47, '2Za9eGyQyKp4S2rVYahzJNM', 0, 0], [1715, 55, 3261, 21, 48, 'djv', 0, 6], [1781, 41, 3267, 15, 48, '3WHD', 0, 6], [1864, 124, 3261, 21, 48, '8ucAV2oj', 0, 6], [2037, 139, 3261, 27, 48, 'baUoLawp6rY', 0, 6], [2196, 76, 3261, 21, 48, 'sRheu', 6, 6], [1715, 226, 3295, 21, 49, 'hAfhkKsI7Jx', 0, 6], [1959, 234, 3295, 21, 49, 'quecbSW4gEdjSGG', 0, 6], [1715, 176, 3329, 27, 50, 'ciaZR8NxiuEXr1', 0, 6], [1910, 140, 3329, 21, 50, 'vicUyHPNcN', 0, 6]]
data_pd =  pd.DataFrame(data_array,columns=["left", "width", "top", "height", "lineNr", "randomWord", "keyWord", "keyWordGroup"])


### group words to keywords
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq
keywords = pd.concat([data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].left + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].width/2, data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].top + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].height/2], axis=1)
words    = pd.concat([data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].left + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].width/2, data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].top + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].height/2], axis=1)
res = vq(words.to_numpy(),keywords.to_numpy())

### remove outliers
import numpy as np
factor = 1.5
limits = []
# calculate limit as limit = mean + factor * stddev for each keyWord
for i in range(len(keywords)):
    limits.append(np.mean(res[1][res[0]==i]) + factor * np.std(res[1][res[0]==i]))

# mark words with distance > limit as outliers
for i in range(len(res[0])):
    if res[1][i] > limits[res[0][i]]:
        res[0][i] = -1

### assign results to dataframe
words['keyWordGroupNew'] = res[0] + 1
keywords['keyWordGroupNew'] = range(1, len(keywords) + 1)
data_pd = pd.concat([data_pd, pd.concat([words['keyWordGroupNew'],keywords['keyWordGroupNew']])], axis=1, join='outer')

# renumber keyWordGroup according to keyWord numbering
dic = dict(zip(range(1, len(keywords) + 1), data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0]['keyWord']))
dic[0] = 0
data_pd.keyWordGroupNew = data_pd.keyWordGroupNew.map(dic)


from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw # pip install Pillow
import random

#Create a empty image object
new_im = Image.new('RGB', ((data_pd["left"]+data_pd["width"]).max() + data_pd["left"].min(), (data_pd["top"]+data_pd["height"]).max()  + data_pd["top"].min() ), (255,255,255))
draw_new_im = ImageDraw.Draw(new_im)

#Create a dictioanry with random colors to assign for each uniq keyWordGroupNew
uniqGroups = data_pd["keyWordGroupNew"].unique()
colors = {}
i = 0
for g in uniqGroups:
    if(g == 0):
        colors[str(g)] = "black" # assign black color for non groups
    else:
        colors[str(g)] =  "hsl(" + str(70 + i * 290 / (len(uniqGroups) - 2)) + ",100%,50%)"
        i += 1

#Write text to the image
for i, row in data_pd.iterrows():
    draw_new_im.text((int(row["left"]), int(row["top"])), str(row["randomWord"]) ,  fill=colors[str(row["keyWordGroupNew"])],font=ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", int(row["height"])))
    if row["keyWord"] > 0:
        draw_new_im.rectangle([row["left"] ,row["top"], row["left"]+row["width"], row["top"]+row["height"]], outline=colors[str(row["keyWordGroupNew"])])

#Save the image
new_im.save("out-std.jpg")
```

As you see in the code, I also made two small improvements to the image generation: uniformly distribute the colors over the hue range from yellow to red and draw frames around the keywords.

Another approach to outlier detection is called [local outlier factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor). This technique marks isolated words thar are not surrounded by other group members as outliers.

```
### group words to keywords
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq
keywords = pd.concat([data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].left + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].width/2, data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].top + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0].height/2], axis=1)
words    = pd.concat([data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].left + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].width/2, data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].top + data_pd[data_pd.keyWord==0].height/2], axis=1)
res = vq(words.to_numpy(),keywords.to_numpy())

# assign results
words['keyWordGroupNew'] = res[0] + 1
keywords['keyWordGroupNew'] = range(1, len(keywords) + 1)

### remove outliers
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
clf = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=10, contamination=0.1)
for i in range(1, len(keywords)+1):
    y_pred = clf.fit_predict(words[words.keyWordGroupNew==i].iloc[:,0:2].to_numpy())
    words.loc[words[words.keyWordGroupNew==i][y_pred==-1].index,'keyWordGroupNew'] = 0   # mark as outlier

### save results to dataframe
data_pd = pd.concat([data_pd, pd.concat([words['keyWordGroupNew'],keywords['keyWordGroupNew']])], axis=1, join='outer')

# renumber keyWordGroup according to keyWord numbering
dic = dict(zip(range(1, len(keywords) + 1), data_pd[data_pd.keyWord!=0]['keyWord']))
dic[0] = 0
data_pd.keyWordGroupNew = data_pd.keyWordGroupNew.map(dic)

# image generation as in previous example ...
```

This doesn't work so well for relatively small groups and the results are visually not so good as with the other method when the keyword is located outside the center of the group.
The result for contamination = 0.1, which is a commonly used value, is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkoPP.jpg). For details see the [original paper](http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/LOF.pdf) and the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html).

Conclusion: both approached give satisfactory results that can be tuned by adjusting the factor x or contamination respectively.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very interesting. I will use your solution and adapt it more